# ReactJS: How to synchronize sessionStorage state between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my app, I have a React component that renders a list of numbers and it also stores the sum of these numbers via `sessionStorage`.

My app also has a component with an `<input />` so that new numbers can be added. This also causes the value stored by `sessionStorage` to be updated. For each number, a `button` exists to allow numbers to be removed, and this immediately updates the value stored in `sessionStorage`.

The problem is that I have another component that uses the value stored in `sessionStorage` as a state using react hooks, but when I update the value in `sessionStorage` the value of state doesn't change.

I'm trying to make it update using `useEffect()`, but it doesn't work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const LimitsIndicator = props => {
  const {
    limits: { total, used },
    currency,
    t,
    type,
  } = props;


  const [limitInUse, setInUse] = useState(sessionStorage.getItem('inUse'));

  useEffect(() => {
    setInUse(sessionStorage.getItem('inUse'))
  })

  return (
    <div>{limitInUse}</div>
  )

}
```

In this image it shows the sum: 250, and the two values: 100 and 150, but the value 150 was canceled, and as you can see in the console, the `sessionStorage` is update, but the value of the sum doesn't change.

[image]

Comment: How are you updating `sessionStorage`?

Comment: `useEffect` will render, in your configuration, at every render. What I guess is happening, is that your code correctly does the work, but since it's not aware that `sessionStorage` has changed, `LimitsIndicator` doesn't have the chance of re-render ( and doesn't update its local state ) in the first place. Since react is not aware that any change in `sessionStorage` may require a re-render of your component, you need to help the tools be aware of that, and force a render.

Comment: Actually, the sessionStorage is updating, I checked in the console when the values change, but as you said, the component is not aware of this update

Comment: Do you know how can I make the component be aware of this update in sessionStorage?

Comment: I added an image to explain better what I'm saying

Comment: What you usually want to do is keep that state inside react, and sync it with a `useEffect` when it change. If you force `LimitsIndicator` to re-render every 1s, you will it update correctly. The stupid solution is: `const [_, dumbSolution] = useState(0); useEffect(()=> { setTimeout(() => dumbSolution(s => s + 1) , 1000) }, [])` <- that's meant for you to understand the issue, so you can move that state back into react, and then sync it into the local storage when it change ( in a `useEffect`

Comment: @Ramon consider using the context api, to manage synchronisation of state (and sessionStorage) between LimitsIndicator and your other input component

Comment: I tried this dumbSolution and It didnt worked, I just replaced the _ to a variable. It is expected to show a counter that updates every second, but it just counts once and stops

Comment: Then I followed Dacre Denny advice and started to learn context API and tried to manage a way to make it work. Context API is very useful in this case, what I did was create like a global variable that stores limitInUse using a Context and a store that Works like flux architecture, but in a easier and simpler way.

Comment: @DacreDenny if you want you can answer this question and I will mark as 'correct'

Comment: @Ramon thanks for that - I just provided an answer and jsFiddle demonstrating this approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve state synchronization between different parts of your app would be via React's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext).

The general idea would be to centralize shared state (ie `limitInUse`) at (or near) the root component of your app via a context provider and then wrap child components that need access to the shared state via the corresponding context consumer:

**1. Create a context for shared state**

Create a context which gives us a state "provider" and a state "consumer". The context consumer will be used to access and interact with shared state throughout the app:

```
const IsUseContext = React.createContext();
```

**2. Define state access for shared state in root component**

Next, define get/set logic for the shared `limitInUse` state. This should be defined in state at (or near) the root level of your app. Here, I define this in the root components `state` object:

```
this.state = {
  /* Define initial value for shared limitInUse state */
  limitInUse : sessionStorage.getItem('inUse'),

  /* Define setter method by which limitInUse state is updated */
  setLimitInUse: (inUse) => {

    /* Persist data to session storage, and update state to trigger re-render */      
    sessionStorage.setItem('inUse', `${ inUse }`)
    this.setState({ limitInUse })
  },
}
```

**3. Render context provider from root component**

Now, render the context's `Provider` component at the root level of your app, and pass the `state` object via the provider's `value` prop. The `state` object will now be accessible from any context consumer used in the app (see below):

```
/* In your app component's render() method, wrap children with context provider */
<IsUseContext.Provider value={ this.state }>
  <LimitsIndicator />
  <InputComponent />
</IsUseContext.Provider>
```

**4. Update shared state in child component**

Finally, we access the shared `limitInUse` from nested child components in our app via our context's consumer. Notice that the state and setter method defined in the object passed to our provider's `value` prop are available and accessible:

```
/* Update shared limitInUse state via context consumer */
return (<IsUseContext.Consumer>
  { ({ setLimitInUse }) => <input onChange={ 
     (event) => setLimitInUse(event.currentTarget.value) } />
  }
</IsUseContext.Consumer>)
```

*Display shared state in child component*

```
/* Access shared limitInUse via context consumer */
return (<IsUseContext.Consumer>
  { ({ limitInUse }) => (<div>  {limitInUse} </div>) }
</IsUseContext.Consumer>)
```

For a full working demo, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dacredenny/4tuqsbwr/3/). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

A few weeks ago, I had a similar issue and created an NPM package to do just that : sharing states between components through the Context API, et **automatically** persisting it in the `localStorage`. Have a look and give it a try : it's called [repersist](https://github.com/ostrebler/repersist).

Example.

**1. You start by defining your shared persisted state in a config file :**

```
import repersist from 'repersist'

const { Provider, useStore } = repersist({
  storageKey: 'mystorekey',

  init: {
    counter: 0,
    search: ''
  },

  actions: {
    increment: () => ({ counter}) => ({
      counter: counter + 1
    }),
    typeSearch: search => ({ search })
  }
})

export { Provider, useStore }
```

**2. Inject the state via Context :**

```
import { Provider } from './storeConfig'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**3. Use it everywhere you want.** Every change triggers a React **and** a `localStorage` update, and that's precisely what you want. Your localStorage is basically in sync no matter what.

```
import { useStore } from './storeConfig'

const SearchField = () => {
  const [{ search }, { typeSearch }] = useStore()
  return (
    <input value={search} onChange={e => typeSearch(e.target.value)}/>
  )
}
```

Everytime your page refreshes, the state gets rehydrated by the `localStorage`.